# How can I translate my messages without using the directive/pipe 'translate'?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate on my angular application.
Currently, the application is monolingual, but I am already preparing for the possibility that I will need to translate it in the future.
Everything works perfectly, but I would like to make sure that if I don't pass directive/pipe 'translate' then my messages must use the default language.
For example, if I have two json files:

1. en.json

   ```
   {"greeting": "Hello"}
   ```
2. it.json

   ```
   {"greeting": "Ciao"}
   ```

In the html:

```
<p> {{greeting | translate}} </p>
```

I would like to write only:

```
<p> {{greeting}} </p>
```

Is this possible?

Sorry for  my English

Comment: In your example, `greeting` is some property of your component. If you pass it to the translate pipe, the value of the property will be used as a key to find a translation. If you don't, it will be printed, as is. How could Angular possibly know that it must be used as a key and be translated if you don't tell it that it must be translated? How would you display something without translating it if that worked? So no, it's not possible. You must use ngx-translate the way it's documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to get all messages.

For example:

```
{{ translator.messages['greetings'] }}
```

And in your service, you create a logic to change the object .messages depending of the user language